# Do I need to release @dynamic variable set with OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC?

Tags: ios

```
@dynamic presentedViewController;

- (void)setPresentedViewController: (UIViewController *) newObj 
{
    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, PresentedViewControllerKey, newObj, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);
}
```

Do I need to release this variable later in time?

Answer (score 0):

It will be `retain`ed, so "Yes, you will need to `release` it".

I believe you just need to match it with:

```
objc_setAssociatedObject(self, PresentedViewControllerKey, nil, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);
```

when you are finished.

Comment: I use `self.presentedViewController = nil`. Could anyone else please confirm this? So, I can firmly accept it as an answer.

Comment: @Tanin your code is the same as i have written when `newObj` is `nil` and there is no override, only one level of abstraction higher. thus, you do need to release it -- setting it to `nil` via setter will accomplish that in many (not all) implementations.

Answer (score 0):

I did same thing , but I use profile to lookup dynamic var , when its parent object dead ,it dead. I did not release it